# Hide "www" text in URL bar (firefox)

Tags: css, firefox, url, text, hide

I was wondering if it is possible to hide the "www" text in the URL bar (only in Firefox) using CSS in Stylish addon or/and Java in Greasemonkey.

I want this to make Firefox even more compact.

---

This is some CSS code that i found for URL bar in firefox that will modify the text size using Stylish. Hope it can help.

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");

.urlbar-input-box,
.searchbar-textbox {
 font-size: 11px !important;
}
```

#### Update

I don't want to remove the "www", I just want to hide it from the url bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`www.example.com` and `example.com` are two different things. Typically they are considered the same, but `www.` is in fact a subdomain.

Therefore, hiding it would be misleading to the user.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use .htaccess for this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Replace example.com with your domain name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this would be a good idea, because `www.` is actually a subdomain therefore removing it may cause problems with certain websites because sometimes they may need `www.` for some stuff. Also if they use other subdomains, they might want cookies (or something that uses the domain) to be set only on their `www.` and not `*.example.com` which is what will happen without `www.` (a subdomain) in front of it.

So no, I don't think it is possible to do this nor is it a good idea. Let the website owners/developers decide if they want `www.` in front or not. It's only an extra three or four characters — it won't do much harm to leave it. :)